# Java digital signature with SHA1withRSA

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa, digital-signature

I'm trying to to apply digital signature to a .txt file. The digital signature is applied successfully but whenever I try to verify it shows me Verified: false.
Here is my code for signing:

```
public void signData(){
   Signature rsa = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
   rsa.initSign(privateKey);
   File f= new File(path);

//read from file
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
  byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) f.length()];
  fis.read(buffer);
  fis.close();
  rsa.update(buffer);
//write to file
  byte[] toWrite=rsa.sign();
  String signPath;
  signPath="Signed-"+f.getName();
  File output=new File(signPath);
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(output);
  fos.write(toWrite);
  fos.flush();
  fos.close();
  System.out.printf("File: %s is now signed in: %s\n\n",path,signPath);
}
```

Reading and verifying:

```
public void verify(){
  Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
  sig.initVerify(publicKey);
  File f= new File(path);
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
  byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) f.length()];
  fis.read(buffer);
  fis.close();
  sig.update(buffer);
  System.out.println("Verified: "+sig.verify(buffer));
}
```

No Errors are shown. KeyPair algorithm used is "RSA".
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your file reading is completely wrong.

Comment: But why??? I use the same method to encrypt and decrypt with cipher and keypair and it works.

Comment: Because you wrote it wrong. Print out the result of your `fis.read(buffer)` and see how much you're reading. That may not be the only problem your code has, but it's the most obvious and basic one.

Comment: I print the result is the same with the text in the file

Comment: Still, your code makes a pretty strong (and stupid) assumption that a single `read()` will return all the bytes. Like I said, may not be the only problem.

Answer (score 3):

For signing, you have the inputs private key and data to sign. The output is the signature.

For verifying, you have the inputs public key and signed data (actually it's the data to sign from the first step). You're missing the signature as an input. It should look like this:

```
sig.update(signedData);
System.out.println("Verified: "+sig.verify(signature));
```

Don't forget to read the signature from the file.

Comment: The file reading should be optimized. See [`class Files`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html)